# Override Keyboard Shortcuts in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, customization

How do I override Keyboard Shortcuts in Firefox so that it can be picked up by web page

For example, I have a webpage that detects ctrl-shift-h which worked fine in version 56 but now in version 96 it brings up a "Show All History" dialog

I am doing many such things so I looking for a generic way to override Firefox keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 6):

I found a way by adding two files under the Firefox directory

**Firefox64\defaults\pref\config-prefs.js**

```
pref("general.config.filename", "config.js");    
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);  
pref("general.config.sandbox_enabled", false);
```

**Firefox64\config.js**

```
let { classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, manager: Cm  } = Components;
const {Services} = Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
function ConfigJS() { Services.obs.addObserver(this, 'chrome-document-global-created', false); }
ConfigJS.prototype = {
 observe: function (aSubject) { aSubject.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', this, {once: true}); },
 handleEvent: function (aEvent) {
   let document = aEvent.originalTarget; let window = document.defaultView; let location = window.location;
   if (/^(chrome:(?!\/\/(global\/content\/commonDialog|browser\/content\/webext-panels)\.x?html)|about:(?!blank))/i.test(location.href)) {
     if (window._gBrowser) {
       let keys = ["key_find", "key_findAgain", "key_findPrevious", "key_gotoHistory", "addBookmarkAsKb", "bookmarkAllTabsKb", "showAllHistoryKb", "manBookmarkKb", "viewBookmarksToolbarKb", "key_savePage", "key_search", "key_search2", "focusURLBar", "focusURLBar2", "key_openDownloads", "openFileKb", "key_reload_skip_cache", "key_viewSource", "key_viewInfo", "key_privatebrowsing", "key_quitApplication", "context-bookmarklink"];
       for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          let keyCommand = window.document.getElementById(keys[i]);
          if (keyCommand != undefined) { 
             keyCommand.removeAttribute("command"); 
             keyCommand.removeAttribute("key"); 
             keyCommand.removeAttribute("modifiers"); 
             keyCommand.removeAttribute("oncommand"); 
             keyCommand.removeAttribute("data-l10n-id"); 
          }
       }
     }
   }
 }
};
if (!Services.appinfo.inSafeMode) { new ConfigJS(); }
```

You can get a list of ids for the keys from the source by putting the following URL in your browser

```
view-source:chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml
```

Comment: Thank you!!  That `view-source` reference is great!!!

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything on the current version (119), and I'm unable to disable shortcuts. No errors, but nothing changes with this config.

Comment: Can you pls tell which default FF Shortcuts get disabled by these 2 files. And whether these 2 files only disable default FF shortcuts or can be used to enable some of them also?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment yet but to extend [zackhalil answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71133816/15245191):

For those on Linux or simillar Unix/Unix-like systems replace `Firefox64` for `/usr/lib/firefox`. Don't be confused with `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox`